# Test Object in XCODE gives does not have member error

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swift

I am trying to test a class called Student.

I made a student object inside my test file:

```
let rice = Student(dateOfBirth: "01/10/2001",Grade: 6,School: "Thompson",PickUp: ["Debra":"Mom","Alf":"Grandpa","Nancy":"Nanny"], Contacts: ["Debra":"555-5555","Alf":"444-444"])
```

And it is ok creating this. However, the moment I start to trying and and test things by using something like

```
rice.DOB, rice.grade
```

it says that Student does not have a member named DOB/grade. However, these calls work outside of the test file.

What am I doing wrong. What do I need to do to be able to test this class?

```
import UIKit
```

public class Student: NSObject{

```
var DOB:String
var grade:Int
var school:String
var pickup:[String:String]
var contacts:[String:String]



public init(dateOfBirth:String, Grade:Int, School:String, PickUp:[String:String], Contacts:[String:String]){
    DOB=dateOfBirth
    grade=Grade
    school=School
    pickup=PickUp
    contacts=Contacts
}
```

function in test file

```
    func testStudent(){
    let rice = Student(dateOfBirth: "01/10/2001",Grade: 6,School: "Thompson",PickUp: ["Debra":"Mom","Alf":"Grandpa","Nancy":"Nanny"], Contacts: ["Debra":"555-5555","Alf":"444-444"])
    XCTAssertTrue(rice.DOB, "01/10/2001")
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Student class?

Comment: there you go. If I am doing anything sloppy let me know I'm new to xcode and swing/objective c.